# How do I tell µTorrent to download files within a torrent sequentially?

Tags: bittorrent, utorrent

Normally µTorrent will download many files simultaneously. Is there a way to tell it to use all bandwidth/connections to download one file and then move to the other?

Setting file priorities does help, but that's a lot of manual work, and two files with the same priority will be downloaded in parallel anyway.

Comment: Is this multiple files in one torrent, or multiple torrents?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Options → Preferences → Queuing → Max. number of active downloads = 1

[image]

Comment: Hey, your image is broken!

Comment: I don't think this does what was asked. This setting is for queuing torrents, not files inside torrents.

Comment: The OP asked for queuing files within a torrent and not the torrent themselves.

Answer (score 3):

Well I don't know how to queue files within a torrent but I quote form another source:

> That this is a bad idea is an understatement. If you don't understand why,
>   then you don't really understand how torrents work so it might be
>   difficult to explain, but imagine when you're doing your grocery
>   shopping and have 100 items on your list, so you walk every single aisle
>   in the store until you get to the milk, because it's #1 on your list.
>   You just passed bread, vegetables, fruit, cereal, frozen foods and got
>   none of it even though you know you needed it because you've decided
>   it's a better idea to get them in order. Now that you've got your milk,
>   next is coffee, so you start at the beginning and walk every aisle
>   again until you get coffee.

If you ask me whether the priority feature for files must also be a bad idea then I would say no. Priority works differently than queuing. When you set a file to high priority, it will be downloaded ahead of the files with lower priority, given that pieces are available for both. But if the pieces for a high priority file are not available, compared to a low priority file, it will download the low priority file.

Comment: That said, as someone who occasionally downloads torrents with sequential files (comics, stories, picture sets, podcasts), it can be useful to prioritize from beginning to end. uTorrent offers a semi-solution with their "Prioritize by file order", but three priorities set once at the beginning does little to help when there are 50 files. :)

Comment: Single-letter typo (too small for me to edit): _form_ should be _from_.